# $(d).attr("id") is undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I have a variable d that I use like this:

```
$(function() {  
    for(i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
        var d = '#days' + i;    
        if ($(d).attr("id").substr(4,2) == 11) {
            $(d).addClass("date_has_event");
            //console.log("diez");
        } else {
            console.log("otro");
        }
    }
}
```

However I get the following error in firebug:

```
$(d).attr("id") is undefined
index.html    (L23)   (?)()()
jquery.min.js (L27)   onreadystatechange()()
jquery.min.js (L27)   onreadystatechange()()
jquery.min.js (L21)   nodeName()([function(), function()], function(), undefined)
onreadystatechange()()
```

I really don't understand why. Does anyone know?

---

**Edit**

I'm sorry for the poor explanation I had to run, here's what's going on a little bit more detailed. I am generating a calendar using javascript. each td has a different id (hence the #days + i) and I am running it from 1 to 31 so I can cover the longer months. However I am getting the error I mentioned above. I am also using the jQuery library to enable me to select more easily (i.e. instead of getElementById just #days)

Comment: Does the element referenced by d have an id? Where are you getting d from?

Comment: What's inside d? Does the selector actually exist?

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript Library too? If so, which one (it looks like jQuery)?

Comment: yes, jQuery sorry about all this

Comment: Some months have less then 31 day, so maybe you're trying to access not existing element. Try to modify check to be like if($(d) && $(d).attr("id").substr(4,2) == 11){...

Comment: changing the question changes the answers :)

Comment: Then tag it as a jQuery question or do some clue that you are using jQuery in the text

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just check if `i == 11`, then do your processing on it?  It would still only fire on `$('#days11')`.  Edit:  If you need to make sure the element exists as well, just slap that into the conditional.

```
$(function(){   
    for(i = 1; i <= 31; i++){
        var d = '#days' + i;    

//       if($(d) && i == 11){            
         if(i == 11){
               $(d).addClass("date_has_event");
               //console.log("diez");
         }else{
               console.log("otro");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: because d contains an id "#days" which I am using to select certain elements

Comment: I know but it seems redundant.  Your creating '#days11', selecting the element that matches '#days11', and seeing if it contains '11'.  That would only return true when 'i == 11'.

Comment: reading more into the code, it seems logical that the 11 arbitrary, why would the 11th always be the only one with a date, and why bother looking for it if you already know that.

Comment: +1: This solution is simpler because it more easily accounts for numbers that could be subsets of other numbers (1 and 10 for example).

Comment: this solution is also less performant. Forcing a javascript loop that will then do a selector each time is bypassing built in functionality to do it the "hard way"

Comment: if($(d)) will always be true. I think you meant: if($(d).length)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, new answer. the way you are doing this is not very "jqueryish".  lets step back a bit. from what I can tell you have an html structure something like:

```
<div id="days1"></div>
<div id="days2"></div>
...
```

You are then running this against every item with a days(num) id?  A better solution is this, if you want to add a class to every element with a date in it, first apply a class:

```
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="days"></div>
```

Your code can then be

```
$(function(){
    $(".days").each(function(i){
        if($(this).substr(4,2) == 11){
            $(this).addClass("date_has_event");
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: You need $("#" + elementId) in jquery.

Comment: I'm sorry what? I'm not selecting off an id, i'm selecting the classes and iterating through them.  This example is fully proper jQuery

Comment: +1 If you're doing a selector in a loop you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are selecting by id, this is redundant:

```
if ($(d).attr("id").substr(4,2) == 11)
```

because the ID attribute of d **is** d.

Is most simple to do:

```
if (i == 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing the closing bracket?

```
$(function() {  
    for(i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
        var d = '#days' + i;    
        if (i == 11) {
            $(d).addClass("date_has_event");
            //console.log("diez");
        } else {
            console.log("otro");
        }
    }
// shouldn't the next line be });
}
```